# Dataframe pivot, lining up new column values without create additional NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

So I'm trying to create a dataframe from a tab delimited text file, with the goal of using the values from one of the columns at the column headers of the dataframe, and using a second column as the values.  When I try to df.pivot, I get what I want but the new columns adds extra NaN values rather than just lining the new rows up properly.

The tab delimited text file basically looks like this:

```
round1    are you healthy   no
round1    are you healthy   yes
round2    are you healthy   yes
round2    are you healthy   yes
round3    are you healthy   no
round3    are you healthy   yes
```

So I've got this:

```
 import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep='\t', usecols=[0,2], names=['colA','colB'])
    df = df.pivot(index=None,columns='colA',values='colB')
    print(df)
```

Which gives me this:

```
colA round1 round2 round3
0        no    NaN    NaN
1       yes    NaN    NaN
2       NaN    yes    NaN
3       NaN    yes    NaN
4       NaN    NaN     no
5       NaN    NaN    yes
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
colA round1 round2 round3
0        no    yes    no
1       yes    yes    yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try

```
df2=df.iloc[:,1:]#Filter out ColA because its basically the index
df2[:]=np.sort(df2.fillna('z').values, axis=0)#Convert NaN to z
df2[df2!='z'].dropna(0)filter not wanted



  round1 round2 round3
0     no    yes     no
1    yes    yes    yes
```

Or

```
df1=df.iloc[:,1:].replace({'yes':1,'no':0}).fillna(-1)#Convert to integers temporarily to allow soring
df1[:]=np.sort(df1.values, axis=0)#Sort dataframe
df1[df1!=-1].dropna(0).astype(bool).replace({True: 'yes',False:'no'})#drop unwanted and replace values to original


 round1 round2 round3
4     no    yes     no
5    yes    yes    yes
```